# Simulate a click on element from a list of elements when pressing previous and next buttons

Tags: jquery, html

I need to create a jQuery script that simulates a click of another element, from a list of elements and each time I press button next, the next element from the list is clicked, and each time I press button previous, the previous element from the list is clicked.

This is the code that partly works, but only clicks once

```js
$('#next').click(function() {
  $('li a').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>
    <span>
    <a href="#" class="current">image</a>
    </span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
    <span>
    <a href="#" class="">image</a>
    </span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
    <span>
    <a href="#" class="">image</a>
    </span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="prev">prev</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
```

In short, when I press button "next", I would like to simulate a click on  tag after element with class "current", but when I press button "previous", I would like to simulate a click on  tag before element with class "current".

Sadly, spans are necessary for this layout, if they wouldn't be present, I could most likely use .next() function as I saw in a similar stack post, but since in my case elements aren't positioned directly one after another, this function doesn't work, or I can't make it work.

Thank you!

Comment: `$('a.current').closest('li')` and then do your next and prev logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating an answer based on @Taplar's comment.

This code sample bases the prev/next advancement on the `a` with the class current.
It locates the `closest li`, and then goes to the next (or previous) one and triggers the click.

> [closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):
>   Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .closest() method searches through these elements and their ancestors in the DOM tree

```js
$('#next').click(function() {
  var $next = $('a.current').closest('li').next().find("a");
  $next = $next.length > 0 ? $next : $("ul li:first-child a"); //if the end get the first one.
  $next.trigger('click');
});
$('#prev').click(function() {
  var $prev = $('a.current').closest('li').prev().find("a");
  $prev = $prev.length > 0 ? $prev : $("ul li:last-child a"); //if the start get the last one.
  $prev.trigger('click');
});
//sample "click" event to toggle the current class
$("li a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("li a").removeClass("current");
  $(this).addClass("current");
});
```

```css
.current {
  background-color: orange;
}

div[id] {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>
    <span>
    <a href="#" class="current">image</a>
    </span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
    <span>
    <a href="#" class="">image</a>
    </span>
    </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>
    <span>
    <a href="#" class="">image</a>
    </span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="prev">prev</div>
<div id="next">next</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much! When the final element is reached, is it possible for script to start from first element again?

Comment: modifed the snippet to recognize the either end and be circular when going to previous or next